How to convert WPF project to single .exe file
I have one WPF project, i need to create exe file with this project to send it to other computers and it will work same. I have some assets in this project, net version 8.0.400
I tried ILMerge, but ILMerge creates a lot of .dll files, i need only one .exe file, trying Publish in Visual Studio don't work, i tried this by cmd, but i had a lot of errors cause of depencies, weavers and etc.

Also you can find some information here
